# Substring in inline HTML

Tags: html

I have a HTML page that uses inline styling and which pulls some variables from different places. Is it possible to write a script within the page to obtain a substring from one of the variable being pulled?

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables, so what are you talking about?

Comment: Is there a substring function is HTML - without using Javascript?

Comment: Are there any other ways to obtain substrings provided I use inline styling? This is for email campaigns that are sent to people.

Comment: Not without using Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, is there a code snippet that I could use to do this? The ones I have been using dont seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it looks like at the moment? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do some programming to achieve the goal of having a substring. Either on the server-side when you generate your structure, or on client-side in the browser. If you do not like Javascript, you can use [other scripting languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946906/why-is-javascript-the-only-client-side-scripting-language-implemented-in-browser), but it is not really advisable to use anything else than the standardly written and well-tested Javascript. Without server-side code or client-side scripting you cannot achieve your goal.